# Trying to press enter key in canvas every 1 seconds using a userscript

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to create an userscript (to use with tampermonkey) which simulates pressing the `Enter` button every 1 seconds.

I have tried

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @require        https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js
// @version      0.1
// @description  desc
// @author       author
// @match        https://example.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


setInterval(() => 
    document.body.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {keyCode : 13}))
, 250);
```

However, the keypress does not seems to works...

The body of the page contains a canvas with the id `gCanvas` and multiples iframes used for ads (which are, I guess, irrelevant since I use an adblocker).

Let me know if I should add a screen of the DOM of the page from the developping tools.

E : in answer to CertainPerformance comment, I've also tried

```
document.getElementById('gCanvas').dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {keyCode : 13}))
```

without result, I also tried with `keydown` and `keyup` event but still without results

Comment: If you're trying to trigger a listener attached by the page, you might have to dispatch the event to the canvas (or to some other element), not the `document.body`, see if that works. The page also might be listening for something other than `keypress`

Comment: added an edit to the question

Comment: Post a link to the site? Hard to tell without seeing what the page's logic is

Comment: the website is mope.io

Comment: Are you trying to bring up / dismiss the chat dialog?

Comment: Not really, i am mostly trying to skip the 15seconds waiting screen after the death of my animal

Comment: Try `{which:13, keyCode:13, key:'Enter', code:'Enter', bubbles:true}`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = elem.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {  console.log(e.key); }, true);

var evt = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {key : "Enter"});
evt.keyCode = 13;

setInterval(() => {

      elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
```